# How to handle failed publish with RabbitMq?

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, easynetq

We are planning to use RabbitMq for our messaging service, we'll publish all the message requests to a RabbitMq durable queue.

For .Net client we've decided to use EasyNetQ, so the question is how should we handle RabbitMq server being while publishing a message?

- Should we catch exception and save the message to database and
  re-publish with scheduled job?
- Should we use circuit-breaker?
- or what else? I'd like to hear your experiences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general if you want to be sure about the publish you can use the [publish confirmation](http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2011/02/10/introducing-publisher-confirms/).

as you can read, you can do that using the transactions or with ConfirmListener.

To handle the broker fails, you can store locally the failed messages then try to re-send them after x seconds.

***Note:*** I don't know how EasyNetQ works, but the native publish is asynchronous, so trap the publish exceptions is not enough. That's why you should use publish confirm to deal with it.